# Find the parameters for which the matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
3a & 2 & b \\
1 & 2& 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

For example I have such a matrix. Can you, please explain how can I find for what values of "a" the matrix has rank 3?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: original question had one parameter, $a$. The OP has since added a second parameter.

---

HINT: Your matrix will have rank $3$ when its determinant is **not equal** to zero. So all values of $a$ are valid, except any value(s) of $a$ for which the determinant is zero.

So, use your favorite method for computing the determinant to obtain a function in $a$, set this function equal to $0$, and solve. Any solution(s) $a_i$ to that equation will be the only value(s) for which the determinant fails to have rank $3$.

Comment: But, for example , it's required the matrix rank to be 2. How can I find the parameter?

Comment: Then you'd need one row, and only one row, such that when the matrix is expressed in reduced row echelon form, the entries are all $0$.

Comment: Now I've changed the condition and we have two parameters. What should I do?                  (Sorry for so many questions.)

Comment: That is very frustrating when you keep changing your question. Please keep it to one question per post, or inquire about variations in comments below answer(s). It is hard to answer a moving target!

Comment: Sorry, it's 100% percent my last target for this topic

Comment: The point of my answer is that whenever the determinant of a $3\times 3$  matrix is $0$, it fails to have rank $3$. So any values of $a$ (or ordered pairs (a, b)) that are found to make the determinant zero are invalid.